# How to deal with the "Payment failed at the payment server" error?

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm trying to get my website integrated with SagePay.
Everything works well untill the payment is made.
Once a client makes payment he/she gets the following error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: crypt in commerce_sagepay_form_redirect_form_validate() (line 55 of /sites/all/modules/commerce_sagepay/includes/commerce_sagepay_form.inc).

Payment failed at the payment server. Please review your information and try again.
```

And I get the following info in the logs:

```
Response could not be converted to tokens
```

Despite these errors the payment was taken, but the order remains in the shopping cart with the status Checkout: Review

I'm using Commerce SagePay 7.x-1.0 and the integration option is Form.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the token conversion, be sure you're using the -dev version (2014-May-23 or later) of [Commerce Sagepay](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_sagepay) before trying anything else.

Note: probably related to: https://drupal.org/node/2115203

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It was something else - suhosin blocked the incoming data from Sagepay

Answer (score 0):

The error which you're having:

```
Payment failed at the payment server. Please review your information and try again.
```

indicates the problem with your SagePay Server Integration. The other Notice is not related to it.

The most common reasons that the Sagepay payment could fail at this point are:

- Network issues:

  - sagepay server can't contact your host from outside the network, so check your firewall,
  - your IP address is not on the white list in Sagepay panel, so try to add it then,

    ```
    Error Code: 4020 : Information received from an Invalid IP address
    ```
- You're posting the invalid form:

  - you're e-mail is in invalid format (this especially happens when synching the db with sanitization and the e-mail looks like: foo@localhost)

    ```
    Error Code: 3078 : The CustomerEMail format is invalid.
    ```
  - the amount is empty or zero (e.g. when using discount/coupons)

    ```
    Error Code: 4009 : The Amount including surcharge is outside the allowed range.
    ```

To check with what kind of issue you're dealing with, you can:

- In Drupal, check the Payment result message from SagePay by going to: Administration » Store » Shopping carts, and click on 'payment' for the Order which you're having problem with,
- In Sagepay, check the logs which should be available somewhere in MySagepay panel.
- Enable additional debugging by going to Administration » Store » Configuration » SagePay settings (e.g. Show Post (for debugging with SagePay)).